# Getting "code" instead of "access_token" in desktop application

Tags: python, facebook, access-token

In spite of setting Auth Token Parameter of my application to `URI Fragment (#access_token=...)`, I keep being redirected to the address with `code` in the text. I'm using Python 2.7 and cookielib for login. Is there anything else I need to do to get `access_token` instead of `code`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The flow is to get the access token, you need that code....But sorry I don't know how to implement this using Python 2.7...